Is constant needing of making ghusl required if it causes hardship
I am a teenage girl who at times experiences uncontrollable sexual thoughts or just general discharge does this constantly require ghusl? I make ghusl multiple times a day from Time to time due to my doubts and it causing overburdening within salah what do I do

Instead of having doubts and complaining about hardship you'd better learn about when ghusl is necessary, since such a knowledge is essential for anybody, there's no excuse in not learning about this topic! Note that hardship in the context of worship means that there's fear of death or similar if one does or leaves something. In your case you may be wasting water while it isn
t even necessary simply because of your ignorance.

Yes and yet my question isn't being answered, I easily become aroused and experience u controllable sexual thoughts and I am confused whether I require ghusl or not. Not only has this effected my peace within salah, it has effected my life right now. I would really appreciate if someone could help me
